# sysdate and current_date have different types?

Tags: oracle

The oracle docs for sysdate and current_date claim they both return DATEs:

- [sysdate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions191.htm#SQLRF06124)
- [current_date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions044.htm#SQLRF00628)

This test, though:

```
alter session set plsql_warnings = 'ENABLE:ALL';
create table test(x date);
create or replace procedure test1 authid definer is
    cursor s is select x from test where current_date > x;
begin for x in s loop null; end loop; end;
/
show errors
drop table test;
drop procedure test1;
```

produces this output:

```
Errors for PROCEDURE TEST1:
LINE/COL  ERROR
3/42      PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan
```

Using sysdate does not give the same warning. I suspect that substituting current_date for sysdate in queries runs a risk of altering the query plan, especially if the date columns are indexed.

edit:

```
select dump(current_date) from dual;
select dump(sysdate) from dual;
```

gives:

```
DUMP(CURRENT_DATE)
Typ=13 Len=8: 223,7,7,9,11,23,55,0

DUMP(SYSDATE)
Typ=13 Len=8: 223,7,7,9,11,23,55,0
```

Comment: I wouldn't lose sleep over it.  Also note that although they are both returning DATE types (we think), they are potentially not returning the same value.One is timezone-adjusted.

Comment: You can dump sysdate, current_date and a date literal to see the internal type numbers. I would expect the optimiser to be clever enough to implicitly convert the sys/current_date to match the column type, not the other way around, so the same query plan would be used. Easy enough to check both plans though. (Or would be if I had access to a DB right now *8-)

Comment: Some evidence (sans an actual test) that query plans can be different: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1049266?tstart=0

Comment: @alex:
`DUMP(CURRENT_DATE)`
`Typ=13 Len=8: 223,7,7,9,11,11,57,0`

`DUMP(SYSDATE)`
`Typ=13 Len=8: 223,7,7,9,11,11,57,0`

Comment: A 'normal' date [is type 12](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020). So strange that you don't get the same warning with sysdate. I think I've seen this raised before, but can't recall if there was a way to avoid the warning without a cast, and it might have been version-specific; which version are you using?

Comment: @OldProgrammer: 2 points: (1) I am in the same timezone as the server (2) the DATE type does not contain timezone information, so both sysdate and current_date return the same value. And we can see that with DUMP. I did not expect the warning from PL/SQL, I cannot find a good explanation for it, and I have no model with which to explain it. Unexplained and unpredictable behaviour makes me nervous.

Comment: @AlexPoole `select distinct version from product_component_version`
gives
`11.2.0.2.0`

Comment: This warning seems to be generated for any date function, and even [with date literals](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5aafd/1) (and [twice when using `to_date()`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5edd/1). Only sysdate seems to be treated differently; which may be related to bugs 9714892, 8760135, etc. Hard to tell if it's a spurious warning - if the selectivity is wrong it could affect the plan I suppose. (See also the plan; only sysdate has notation "@!", as in `filter("X"<SYSDATE@!)`). So I don't think it's about the types exactly, but about special handling for sysdate?

Comment: Hi, the type of sysdate and current_date is the same but current_date retrieve data from your client or better from the session time zone. So you can not easily change sysdate with current_date.

Comment: Hi, as Alex Pool said this warning can be related to 8760135 bug. If your version is lower than 11.2.0.2 try the same query in 11.2.0.2

Comment: This also exhibits in 11.2.0.3.5 and 12c @Giova.

Comment: Interestingly, you do NOT get the warning if you use "SYS.STANDARD.CURRENT_DATE" in lieu of just "CURRENT_DATE".

Answer (score 1):

1) CURRENT_DATE returns the current date in the session time zone. Do you really need current_date?
If not, stick with sysdate. That will work your procedure

2) If you still need CURRENT_DATE, following is the solution. Store the value of current_date into variable and it will resolve your problem. Let me if this answers your question.

```
drop table test;
create table test(x date);
create or replace procedure test1 authid definer 
is
dateVar date;
cursor s is select x from test where dateVar > x;
begin 
dateVar:=current_date;
for x in s loop null; 
end loop; 
end;
/
SQL> show errors
No errors.
```

Comment: Did above answer fixed your issue?

Comment: I understand the difference between current_date sysdate timezone semantics. It doesn't matter in my case because both server and client are in the same timezone. I was actually looking at the feasibility of recommending that we use current_date (ANSI standard) preferably to sysdate, and discovered that current_date was not naively substitutable for sysdate.

Comment: ok. The procedure I gave above is working for current_date in case if you want to use